# Elasticsearch cluster isn't shown up

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, curl, ansible

Hi I installed Elasticsearch 6.6 with Ansible playbook over a cluster with 3 nodes. 
All nodes are on the same port.

When I run the query:

```
curl  -u es_admin:<pass> -X GET 'https://<hostname1>:9201/_nodes/process?pretty' -k
```

I see only one node in the cluster:

```
{
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "new_cluster",
  "nodes" : {
    "Qlqcbgs_QmWXpglNVoOApQ" : {
      "name" : "node1",
      "transport_address" : "<IP_address>:9301",
      "host" : "<hostname1>",
      "ip" : "<IP_address>",
      "version" : "6.6.0",
      "build_flavor" : "default",
      "build_type" : "rpm",
      "build_hash" : "<build_hash_number>",
      "roles" : [
        "master",
        "data",
        "ingest"
      ],
      "attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "16653647872",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20",
        "ml.enabled" : "true"
      },
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 11674,
        "mlockall" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the same output for each node separately:

```
curl  -u es_admin:<pass> -X GET 'https://<hostname2>:9201/_nodes/process?pretty' -k
curl  -u es_admin:<pass> -X GET 'https://<hostname3>:9201/_nodes/process?pretty' -k
```

Under elasticsearch.template.yml I do see the other nodes. For example if I go to node1 I see the other two:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:
- <hostname2>:9301
- <hostname3>:9301
```

here is elasticsearch.yml:

```
node.name: node1

network.host: <hostname>

http.port: 9201

transport.tcp.port: 9301

node.master: true

node.data: true

node.ingest: true

search.remote.connect: true



#################################### Paths ####################################

# Path to directory containing configuration (this file and logging.yml):

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch/node1

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch/node1

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:
- <hostname2>:9301
- <hostname3>:9301



xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial


node.ml: true


xpack.ml.enabled: true


xpack.security.audit.enabled: true

xpack.security.enabled: true



xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.ssl.keystore.path: **path**
xpack.ssl.keystore.password: *passwd*
xpack.ssl.truststore.path: **path**
xpack.ssl.truststore.password: *passwd*
```

What should be done in order to see all the nodes under the same cluster?

Comment: looks they they have not joined the cluster, can you show your elasticsearch.yml file? also check the elasticsearch logs to see if there are error message about the discovery process and which version of es you are using?

Comment: Logs are too long I can barely understand if there is an error. I am using ES6.6
I will share elasticsearch.yml file in the question body.

Comment: @PrernaGupta I added elasticsearch.yml to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 6.X you also need to set [`discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/discovery-settings.html#minimum_master_nodes) to say to your nodes what is the minimum number of master nodes required to form a cluster.

Since you didn't set it, each of your nodes think they are the master node and they won't join any cluster.

Set it to `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2` in each `elasticsearch.yml` file and restart your nodes.

Comment: I added  discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2  before discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: is that ok? Also, why 2? does it matter? I have 3 nodes in my cluster

Comment: It is how the quorum is calculated, `(master_eligible_nodes / 2) + 1`, this quorum exists to avoid a problem know as [`split brain`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/modules-node.html#split-brain), with 3 nodes, the minimum quorum is 2. The order of the config doesn't matter, it just needs to exist in all your nodes.

Comment: Added discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2 and then systemctl restart elasticsearch@node1.service but still Curl shows 1 node in the cluster. Is that the way you meant to restart my nodes?

Comment: Hi, I noticed that when I install ES without ssl, and add your suggestion, it will work. But when installing it with ssl enabled, it is still not shown as cluster ...

Comment: Did you follow the [documentation tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/configuring-tls.html) ? Do you have a valid license? Using ssl needs x-pack security, which is a **paid** feature on 6.6 (but is free on 6.8+ and 7.1+)

Comment: Yup I am using x-pack security. However I use xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial

Comment: Hi, can you please refer to another question ES related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370292/elasticsearch-upgrade-using-yum 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think all discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts must be the same in all node.

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:
- <hostname1>:9301
- <hostname2>:9301
- <hostname3>:9301
```

please try this or just:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["hostname1:9301"]
```